what is the best way to get the amount of token1 i can get for 1 token0 in a pool
async function getPoolData() {
  const provider = await new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545/");
  const signers = await provider.getSigner();
  console.log("Pass 1");
  const uniswapV3Factory = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984";
  
  const WETH9 = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";
  const USDC = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48";
 // const DAI = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F"
  const factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(
    uniswapV3Factory,
    FactoryAbi.abi,
    signers
  );
  const poolAddress = await factoryContract.getPool(WETH9, USDC, 100);
  const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(
    poolAddress,
    IUniswapV3Pool.abi,
    signers
  );
  const slot0 = await poolContract.slot0();
  const currentTick = slot0.tick;
  const tickSpacing = await poolContract.tickSpacing();
  const tickLow = floorDivideBigInt(currentTick, tickSpacing) * tickSpacing;
  const tickHigh = tickLow + tickSpacing;

  console.log(currentTick: ${currentTick}, tickLow: ${tickLow}, tickHigh: ${tickHigh});
}

what is the best way to get the amount of token1 i can get for 1 token0 in a pool and the other way around as quickly, with as little delay and as accurate as possible?
I am using Uniswap V3
Please help , If anyone knows.

Using the JS libraries including Uniswap-V3 SDK and JSBI, the amounts required for adding liquidity can be calculated by fetching the sqrtPriceX96 from the pool contract.
Here's the code to achieve the same:
const JSBI = require('jsbi')
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const { FullMath } = require('@uniswap/v3-sdk')
const UniswapV3FactoryABI = require('./abis/UniswapV3Factory.json');
const UniswapV3PoolABI = require('./abis/UniswapV3Pool.json');
const RPC_URL = "JSON_RPC_URL"
const WETH = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"; // quote
const USDC = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48"; // base
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);

const uniswapV3Factory = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984";

const factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(
    uniswapV3Factory,
    UniswapV3FactoryABI,
    provider
);

async function getSqrtPriceX96(fee) {

    const poolAddress = await factoryContract.getPool(WETH, USDC, fee);
    const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(
        poolAddress,
        UniswapV3PoolABI,
        provider
    );

    console.log(poolAddress);

    const slot0 = await poolContract.slot0();
    const sqrtPriceX96 = JSBI.BigInt(parseInt(slot0.sqrtPriceX96));

    return sqrtPriceX96;
}

async function main(
    inputAmount,
    baseTokenDecimals,
    quoteTokenDecimals,
    fee
) {

    const sqrtPriceX96 = await getSqrtPriceX96(fee);

    const ratioX192 = JSBI.multiply(sqrtPriceX96, sqrtPriceX96);

    const baseAmount = JSBI.BigInt(inputAmount * (10 ** baseTokenDecimals));

    const shift = JSBI.leftShift(JSBI.BigInt(1), JSBI.BigInt(192));

    const quoteAmount = FullMath.mulDivRoundingUp(ratioX192, baseAmount, shift);
    console.log(`${inputAmount} USDC: `, (quoteAmount.toString() / (10 ** quoteTokenDecimals)), 'WETH');
    console.log(`${inputAmount} WETH: `, inputAmount / (quoteAmount.toString() / (10 ** quoteTokenDecimals)), 'USDC');

}

const fee = 100;  // 100 for 0.01% fee-tier, 3000 for 0.3% fee-tier, etc.
const amount = 1;

main(amount, 6, 18, fee);

P.S. You can get the JSON_RPC_URL for Ethereum Mainnet (or any other listed network) by getting the API key from RPC providers like Alchemy or Infura.
If privacy is not a concern in your case, then you can also opt for some public JSON RPC url like https://ethereum-rpc.publicnode.com and others as listed on Chainlist.

The answer you given is working in the case of swaping , not for liquidity pool. Any way thanks brother.

@unnikrishnan, do you want get the liquidity volume at the current price ?

@unnikrishnan, I've edited my answer. Now, it's calculating the amounts required for adding liquidity (provided that you select the Full range while setting the price range on the UI). Please check.
